# Style Radio Inputs in a Facebook Application

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins

Hi to the community,
i'm trying to build a facebook application with a simple form with 3 radio buttons and i use a JQuery plugin that works fine if i test the html page local or online, after i include the fb api

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '0000000000000000000',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```

it stops using the custom styling from the plugin,
the plugin i use is here!

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

does anyone else know what i'm missing or how i can include it in my app?

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: what's the error you see in JavaScript console?

Comment: I don't get an error, for some reason facebook block's the included .js file, loads but don't run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order with the facebook js and squery are important in th ehtml structure, try to change what its load first.